# Aggregate totals for all Sub-document keys

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following recordset of users with dozens of achievements fields:

```
{
  name: 'John',
  achievements: {
    champion: true,
    commander: false
    rockstar: true,
    ...
  }
},
{
  name: 'Lynda',
  achievements: {
    champion: false,
    commander: true,
    best_player: true,
    ...
  },
},
  ...
}
```

Can I aggregate number of each achievement without map-reduce?

```
{
  champion: 10,
  commander: 5,
  best_player: 2,
  rockstar: 1,
  smth_else: 0,
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please? *"without map-reduce"* implies you have already read some answers and those seem to point to that as being the solution. I presume you mean "total all the keys under achievements". Which version of MongoDB do you actually have? Since that also plays a major factor.

Comment: With `db.collection.mapReduce` this can be done easy. But I believe that there is a way to do this with `db.collection.aggregate`. 

MongoDB version v3.4.9

Comment: If the list of achievements is not dynamic and you can hardcode it in the query, you can aggregate it with earlier versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with the aggregation framework, then you need at least MongoDB 3.4.4 in order to use the supported [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) and [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/).

```
db.getCollection('people').aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "achievements": { 
      "$map": {
        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$achievements" },
        "in": {
          "k": "$$this.k",
          "v": { "$cond": ["$$this.v", 1, 0] }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$achievements" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$achievements.k",
    "v": { "$sum": "$achievements.v" }    
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$v" } }  
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
  }}
])
```

If you don't have that version available, then then only approach is to use mapReduce. Before those operators were introduced there is no way to work with the keys of an object without actually declaring all of them explicitly. You can only do the same sort of operation in JavaScript code. Which is what `mapReduce` does:

```
db.getCollection('people').mapReduce(
  function() {
    emit(null, Object.keys(this.achievements).map(
      k => ({ [k]: this.achievements[k] ? 1 : 0 })
    ).reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,curr),{}));
  },
  function(key,values) {
    return [].concat.apply([],values.map(
      v => Object.keys(v).map( k => ({ k, v: v[k] }))
    )).reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{
      [curr.k]: ( acc.hasOwnProperty(curr.k) )
        ? acc[curr.k] + curr.v
        : curr.v
    }),{});
  },
  { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```